# fatal: unable to access OpenSSL/3.1.2: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: azure-devops, openssl, git-bash

I am trying to clone a repo from DevOps using Git Bash, with the git clone command

I'm getting the error message:

fatal: unable to access OpenSSL/3.1.2: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

I was trying to clone a DevOps Repo, I was expecting the repo to be cloned on to my local drive so I could make changes

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways to resolve the issue:

1. Use the PowerShell script mentioned in the documentation "[**TLS 1.2 enforcement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/hybrid/connect/reference-connect-tls-enforcement#powershell-script-to-enable-tls-12)" to enable TLS 1.2 on your local machine.
2. Enable unsafe legacy renegotiation via setting the option '**`UnsafeLegacyServerConnect`**' in the OpenSSL conf (**`openssl.cnf`**) on your local machine. you need to add this option under '**`[system_default_sect]`**' section in the **`openssl.cnf`** file. See below example as reference.

   ```ini
   . . .

   [system_default_sect]
   Options = UnsafeLegacyServerConnect
   ```